# How do I configure karma jasmine to work with my typescript react app.

Tags: typescript, karma-jasmine, create-react-app

I am trying to create a typescript react app that uses jasmine for tests. To do this I created a new project with [react-create-app-typescript](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript) I then followed this article to install karma and jasmine: https://github.com/IntrepidPursuits/react-page-object/blob/master/docs/faq/installation-karma-jasmine.md

I followed the directions, but I am getting this error from running "npm test".
[image]

Should the tests in the test dir use ts instead of js? Do I need to make changes in the config/karma.conf.js file? Should I have taken a different approach to setting up karma-jasmine in my project?

If this helps here is a link to my project: https://github.com/hpufo/ProtList

Comment: I don't think the `ENV_VAR=value somecommand` syntax works on Windows, try something like [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) for setting those values in a compatible way.

Comment: Tried that and got: 'cross-env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.